# Calculating values of multiple col of different rows?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a problem in my logic. I have a table which has 10 col. Those 10 col contains 8 col of different question. Each questions is answered by yes and no and each ROW questions have been answered differently(Please look at the table below).I want to calculate marks for One particular row at a time
But for some reason when I fetch value I have different title and description of rows but same marks for each rows(Please see the output below).And I am getting 4.5 marks for each row. All I wanted is separate marks for different rows.

[image: MY TABLE STRUCTURE]
[image: THE OUTPUT]

The value of YES IS 1
The value of NO IS 0.
**and I am multiplying those values with my marking scheme.**

I am calculating the value with the help of this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include 'common.php';
$command = "SELECT Title, Description, Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5, Question6, Question7, Question8  FROM sachjot";
// prepare and executing
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($command);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // get all result using this

$p; // variable to store all the values of different questions per row

foreach($results as $data){
  $data['Question1'];
  $data['Question2'];
  $data['Question3'];
  $data['Question4'];
  $data['Question5'];
  $data['Question6'];
  $data['Question7'];
  $data['Question8'];


  if ($data['Question1'] == "YES"){
        $p +=  1 * 1;        // 1 is the marking scheme marks
  }else{
    $p = 0 * 1;
  }

  if ($data['Question2'] == "YES"){
    $p +=  + 1 * 0.5;       // 0.5 is the marking scheme marks
  }else{
    $p += 0 * 0.5;
  }

  if($data['Question3'] == "YES"){
    $p += 1 * 2;           // 2 is the marking scheme marks
  }else{
    $p += 0 *2;
  }

  if($data['Question4'] == "YES"){
    $p += 1*1;
  }else{
    $p += 0 * 1;
  }

  if($data['Question5'] == "YES"){
    $p += 1 *1.5;
  }else{
    $p += 0 * 1.5;
  }

  if($data['Question6'] == "YES"){
    $p += 1 * 1;
  }else{
    $p += 0 * 1;
  }

  if($data['Question7'] == "YES"){
    $p += 1 * 1;
  }else{
    $p += 0 *1;
  }

  if($data['Question8'] === "YES"){
    $p += 1 * 2;
  }else{
    $p += 0*2;

}
}
 ?>
```

And fetching them with the help of this code:

```
              <?php
        foreach($results as $row){
          // echo "<tr><td>".$row["rank"]."</td>";
          echo "<tr><td>".$row['Title']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$p."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Description']."</td></tr>";
         }
        ?>
```

Comment: why don't you just add each mark instead of multiplying for example 1 by the 1.5 as you're producting the same result so $p += 1.5. you also don't need to include an else as you are adding 0 each time. The result doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<?php
include_once('common.php');
$command = "SELECT * FROM `sachjot`";
// prepare and executing
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($command);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // get all result using this

$p; // variable to store all the values of different questions per row

function getMark($answer, $mark = 1){ // get the answer and the mark (1 is the mark by default, but you can change this. It means that you can simply not pass the parameter if the value is actually 1)
    $result = 0;
    if($answer == 'YES'){
        $result = $mark;
    }
    return $result;
}
foreach($results as $data){
    $p = 0;
    $p += getMark($data['Question1'], 1); // provide the answer and the mark
    $p += getMark($data['Question2'], .5);
    $p += getMark($data['Question3'], 2);
    $p += getMark($data['Question4'], 1);
    $p += getMark($data['Question5'], 1.5);
    $p += getMark($data['Question6'], 1);
    $p += getMark($data['Question7'], 1);
    $p += getMark($data['Question8'], 2);

    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$data['Title'].'</td>
        <td>'.$p.'</td>
        <td>'.$data['Description'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Much appreciated

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with the variable in the function, I updated it. Check the `getMark()` function. I swear it's important. **Very important**.

Comment: oh ok, I didn't see that. and  thank you for making is correct